# Unit Test case in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, code-coverage, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage, grunt-contrib-jasmine

I am trying to write a test case for if conditions within a loop, I however do not have it as part of a filter. Is there any way I can test the if conditions within a loop. My test case does not execute this line of code at all.

Below is my controller code

```
   $scope.init = function()
   {
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tempdata.length; i++) { //mapping of the status   to text

            if ($scope.tempdata[i].Status == 'U') {
                    $scope.statusText = 'text1';

                }
                if ($scope.tempdata[i].Status == 'A' || $scope.tempdata[i].Status == 'W') {
                    $scope.statusText = 'text2';
                }
                if ($scope.tempdata[i].Status == 'F') {
                    $scope.statusText = 'text3';
                }
                if ($scope.tempdata[i].Status == 'P') {
                    $scope.statusText = 'text4';
                }
                if ($scope.tempdata[i].Status == 'E') {
                    $scope.statusText = 'text5';
                }
                if ($scope.tempdata[i].Status == 'S') {
                    $scope.statusText = 'text6';
                }
                  }
          }
```

Below is my test case

```
 it('should set the status', function() {
   scope.responseSet = true;
   var mockTempData =[{'Status': 'F'}];
    scope.tempdata = mockTempData
    scope.init();  
    expect(scope.statusText).toBe(text3);
});
```

When i run karma my test case fails with Expected '' to be text3.

Comment: A `switch($scope.tempdata[i].Status)` would look neater. Also, shouldn't your test be `expect(scope.statusText).toEqual('text3')` (as in the string "text3")?

Comment: Seems to work ok over here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/4t8W9APotPwcvzvvuPxQ?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to tell if you show how you are "injecting" scope into your controller test. However, I find it very helpful to debug my unit tests to carefully step through them and make sure everything is as I expect each step along the way.

You should also have your last line be

```
expect(scope.statusText).toBe('text3');
```

Note that text3 in your test code should be changed to 'text3' since this is a string in your actual controller, not a variable name.